# If the gradient of a vector is zero, does that imply that the laplacian of the vector is a null vector?

Tags: vector-analysis, laplacian, divergence-operator

Suposse $\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = 0$

Does that imply that $\Delta \vec{u} = \vec{0}$

Thank you!

Comment: Careful, the gradient operator only applies to scalar fields. It looks like you have specified that the divergence of the vector field $\vec{u}$ (judging by the arrow and the dot after the $\nabla$) is zero.

Answer (score 0):

To show that it is not true (note that the Laplacian has to be taken component wise for this question to even make sense), take a look at the vector field
$$\vec{u}(x,y,z)= \begin{pmatrix} y^2\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and show that the divergence vanishes but the Laplacian does not.

Comment: Thank you for the example!